In TipTap v.2.4.0, I have the error 'Could not resolve @tiptap/pm' with the extension StarterKit
I installed TipTap v.2.4.0 in my React project following their guide but I get the errors:
Could not resolve "@tiptap/pm/state"
Could not resolve "@tiptap/pm/gapcursor"
Could not resolve "@tiptap/pm/dropcursor"
Could not resolve "@tiptap/pm/history"
Could not resolve "@tiptap/pm/state"
Could not resolve "@tiptap/pm/view"
Could not resolve "@tiptap/pm/keymap"
Could not resolve "@tiptap/pm/model"
Could not resolve "@tiptap/pm/transform"
Could not resolve "@tiptap/pm/commands"
Could not resolve "@tiptap/pm/schema-list"

Tho @tiptap/pm v.2.4.0 is installed. I think it's linked to the StarterKit extension.

The problem for me was that @tiptap/starter-kit  was missing to declare @tiptap/pm as a peer-dependency. Usually with npm it still works but with yarn you might need to declare it manually in the .yarnrc.yml like so:
packageExtensions:
  '@tiptap/starter-kit@*':
    dependencies:
      '@tiptap/pm': '*'


Can you see tiptap/pm in your package.json file and the related prosemirror packages in node modules?
Try to run npm install @tiptap/pm because I don't think its included with the installation of main tiptap package
